# About creating an image control with Xaml in c#

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, image-processing, dicom

I have been working on this project in C# dealing with opening up a dicom image in C# with ClearCanvas, I have this reoccuring error that I cannot fix. My code is as follows

```
enter 
    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string filename = @"C:\Users\Don jar\Pictures\Xray pics\fluro.dcm";
        DicomFile dicomFile = new DicomFile(filename);
        dicomFile.Load(DicomReadOptions.Default);
        foreach (DicomAttribute attribute in dicomFile.DataSet)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Tag: {0}, Value: {1}", attribute.Tag.Name, attribute.ToString());
        }

        int bitsPerPixel = dicomFile.DataSet.GetAttribute(DicomTags.BitsStored).GetInt32(0, 0);
        int width = dicomFile.DataSet.GetAttribute(DicomTags.Columns).GetInt32(0, 0);
        int height = dicomFile.DataSet.GetAttribute(DicomTags.Rows).GetInt32(0, 0); 
        int stride = width * 2;
        byte[] bitmapBuffer = (byte[])dicomFile.DataSet.GetAttribute(DicomTags.PixelData).Values;


        BitmapSource bitmapSource = BitmapImage.Create(width, height, 96, 96, System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Gray16, null, bitmapBuffer, stride);

        image1.Source = bitmapSource; 


    }code here
```

I've receiving an error on the last line

```
image1.Source = bitmapSource;
```

the error states that

Error   1   The name 'image1' does not exist in the current context.

However, after doing some research, I read that I have to create an image control defined in the XAML of the page that I will display the Dicom image on. Hence it should be in this format

```
enter <Window x:Class="WpfImageTest.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"> 
<Grid> 
<Image Name="image1" />
</Grid>code 
</Window>
```

with code behind

```
    enter public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Create source
    BitmapImage myBitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

    // BitmapImage.UriSource must be in a BeginInit/EndInit block
    myBitmapImage.BeginInit();
    myBitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(@"E:\Pictures\avatar.jpg");
    myBitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth = 200;
    myBitmapImage.EndInit();

    //set image source
    image1.Source = myBitmapImage;

}code here
```

My question is how would I incorporate this in my project, I've added XAML as reference and now i'm clueless as to how to proceed further. Do i incorporate this code into my cs file or build a completely cs file. I will be grateful for any information. I thank you very much

Comment: Your xaml and cs file should be implementation of one class. Your cs file is the partial implementation of the MainWindow class

XAML file (showing the class) (MainWindow.xaml)

    <Window x:Class="WindowGrid.MainWindow"
    ... further things

CS file (MainWindow.xaml.cs)

    public partial class MainWindow : Window

Answer (score 0):

Posted as an answer to show the formatting (between two files)

Your xaml and cs file should be implementation of one class. Your cs file is the partial implementation of the MainWindow class

XAML file (showing the class) (MainWindow.xaml)

```
<Window x:Class="WindowGrid.MainWindow"
... further things
```

CS file (MainWindow.xaml.cs)

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
```